# retain array data outside of method objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, nsmutablearray

**I have an array, `players`, with two strings inside it: `player1` and `player2`. Here is my .h file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface hardOne : UIViewController {
        UISwitch *hard1ON;
        NSMutableArray *players;
        NSString *player1, *player2;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *hard1ON;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL switchState;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *players;

- (IBAction) switchValueChanged;
@end
```

**The array is initialized in the viewDidLoad then the data is entered into that array in two IBActions in my .m file:**

```
#import "hardOne.h"

@interface hardOne () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldOne;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldTwo;

@end

@implementation hardOne
@synthesize hard1ON;
@synthesize players;
@synthesize textFieldOne;
@synthesize textFieldTwo;

BOOL switchState;
int counter = 0;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [hard1ON setOn:switchState animated:NO];
    //read player names to user defaults
    [textFieldOne setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"player1"]];
    [textFieldTwo setText:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"player2"]];
    self.players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.players);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction) switchValueChanged
{
    counter += 1;
    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
        switchState = 0;
    } else {
        switchState = 1;
    }
    if (hard1ON.on) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"theChange" object:nil];
    } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"theChange2" object:nil];
    }
}

- (IBAction) returnKey1
{
    player1 = [textFieldOne text];
    [self.players addObject:(player1)];
    //set player1's name to user defaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[textFieldOne text] forKey:@"player1"];
}

- (IBAction) returnKey2
{
    player2 = [textFieldTwo text];
    [self.players addObject:(player2)];
    //set player2's name to user defaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[textFieldTwo text] forKey:@"player2"];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}

@end
```

If I use `NSLog` in the second IBAction, once it is complete, the array is correctly displayed in the console with the strings `player1` and `player2`, however if I try to use the array anywhere else it is `null`. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How is `player1` and `player2` defined in your class? Why do you need these properties at all if you store them into the array? Also, it is usually advisable to use `self.` to access properties, e.g `self.players = ...`.

Comment: what do you mean anywhere else? Pls add code for the entire .h and .m file. Also, are you using ARC

Comment: Thinking about it you're correct, they're unnecessary variables. How come that's advisable? Either way the `player1` and `player2` variables don't affect the array becoming null in other methods, do they?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ARC. I will now update the code. For instance, if I try to `NSLog` the array in viewDidLoad after it's set, it appears `null`. The reason I'm doing this is because I'm trying to access the `players` array from another class for a `SearchViewController`.

Comment: Yoy might b allocating the player class once again ...that's y

Comment: if I change it all to `self.players` the array is still empty

Comment: Where else are you logging to show that it is still nil? I assume the NSLog in the viewDidLoad shows the array.

Comment: I log it in the IBAction and the array is correct with player1 and player2, but if I leave the view and reenter it, the viewDidLoad logs an empty array, not null anymore.

Comment: Wha exactly do you mean by, leave the view?"  Are you instantiating a new view and expecting it to have the old view's instance variables?

Comment: The view controller with the array is a popover segue from the main view. How do I keep the array objects when I leave the view?

Answer (score 1):

You've got two definitions for players.

One is a property. It's never initialized and so it's null.  You use it as self.players and backed by the instance variable _players.

One is an instance variable. It's initialized in viewDidLoad. It's not nil.

This is almost surely a mistake.

Comment: very good point.. I've changed all the `players` to `self.players`. The array is still empty when I open the view controller after entering information into it though

Comment: Get rid of the instance value. Change the property from (nonatomic, retain) to (nonatomic, strong). I think you'll find it's ok.

Comment: `retain` == `strong` under ARC

Comment: sure. Still, `strong` is better style.  <shrugs> if user2178970 really wants help, she's going to have to either give us some evidence or (better) learn to debug this herself.

Comment: What evidence do you want? Screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding the array as a private instance variable i.e add it to the .m file in the @interface with

```
NSMutableArray *players;
```

then you should be able to access the array just by using "players" instead of self.players. This should be then be available throughought the whole of your class. If this doesn't work then I would say the problem doesn't lie within the scope of your variable but rather the with some other code.

Comment: This just makes your code harder to read - by not using the underscore convention for ivars, and not using properties you set yourself up for some maintainability problems.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to access the array from another class too, which rules out using an instance variable as far as I'm aware.